# How can I use in_array if the needle is an array?

Tags: php, arrays, search, compare

I have 2 arrays, the value will be loaded from database, below is an example:

```
$arr1 = array(1,2,3);
$arr2 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
```

What I want to do is to check if **all the values** in `$arr1` exist in `$arr2`. The above example should be a `TRUE` while:

```
$arr3 = array(1,2,4,5,6,7);
```

comparing `$arr1` with `$arr3` will return a `FALSE`.

Normally I use `in_array` because I only need to check single value into an array. But in this case, `in_array` cannot be used. I'd like to see if there is a simple way to do the checking with a minimum looping.

UPDATE for clarification.

First array will be a set that contains unique values. Second array can contain duplicated values. They are both guaranteed an array before processing.

Comment: Might be worth clarifying: Are you looking for normal "set" semantics? What result would you expect if the second array was array(1,2,4,3)? What if the first was array(1,1,1,1)? Or are they illegal?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Use [`array_diff()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

```
$arr1 = array(1,2,3);
$arr2 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
$arr3 = array_diff($arr1, $arr2);
if (count($arr3) == 0) {
  // all of $arr1 is in $arr2
}
```

Comment: This is not working well when array values are string.

Comment: @Tamim did you find any alternate solution for string values

Comment: Why would anyone claim that `array_diff()` is unsuitable on arrays of strings? `array_diff()` is perfectly capable.

Answer (score 45):

You can use [array_intersect](https://www.php.net/array_intersect) or [array_diff](https://www.php.net/array_diff):

```
$arr1 = array(1,2,3);
$arr2 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);

if ( $arr1 == array_intersect($arr1, $arr2) ) {
    // All elements of arr1 are in arr2
}
```

However, if you don't need to use the result of the intersection (which seems to be your case), it is more space and time efficient to use array_diff:

```
$arr1 = array(1,2,3);
$arr2 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
$diff = array_diff($arr1, $arr2);

if ( empty($diff) ) {
    // All elements of arr1 are in arr2
}
```

Comment: The behavior of `array_intersect` is different that `array_diff`. `array_intersect` return common elements. If the `$arr1` contains values that does not exist in `$arr2` the result will be different of `array_diff` and this result will be wrong for the anwser.

Answer (score 5):

You can try use the [array_diff()](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) function to find the difference between the two arrays, this might help you. I think to clarify you mean, all the values in the first array must be in the second array, but not the other way around.

Comment: Yes Sam. All `$arr1` values must be appear in second array, to get a `TRUE` condition, otherwise, `FALSE`. I'll take a look for the `array_diff()`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case I needed to check if a pair of ids was processed before or not. So simple `array_diff()` did not work for me.

Instead I generated keys from ids sorted alphabetically and used them with in_array:

```
<?php
$pairs = array();
// ...
$pair = array($currentId, $id);
sort($pair);
$pair = implode('-', $pair);
if (in_array($pair, $pairs)) {
    continue;
}
$pairs[$pair] = $pair;
```

This is probably not an optimum solution at all but I just needed it for a dirty script to be executed once.

Answer (score 0):

```
function in_2array($needle,$haystack,$full_search=false){
    $ret = false;
    foreach($needle as $search){
        if(in_array($search,$haystack)){
            $ret = true;
            if(!$full_search){
                break;
            }
        }else if($full_search){
            $ret = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}

if(in_2array($arr1,$arr2,true)){
echo 'It`s Ok!';
}
```