# php multiple array values in_array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm not sure if it's possible to do it with in_array. What I need is to verify that all given values exist in array. For example:

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
$b = array(1,2,3);

if(in_array($b, $a)) {
   return true
} else {
  return false
}
```

Note that all the values from $b must exist in $a in order to return true.

Comment: Maybe walk through `$b` in foreach and than test with `in_array`?

Comment: try `array_intersect` or `array_diff`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
$b = array(1,2,3);

if(!array_diff($b, $a)) {
   echo '$b is subset of $a';
} else {
  echo '$b isn`t subset of $a';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function arrayExists($needle, $haystack) {
    return sizeof(array_intersect($needle, $haystack)) == sizeof($needle);
}
```

also can use this if your needle array has duplicate values:

```
function arrayExists($needle, $haystack) {
    return sizeof(array_intersect(array_unique($needle), array_unique($haystack))) == sizeof(array_unique($needle));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Duplicate** of [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304436/in-array-but-needle-is-array-what-the-alternative-for-it).

**Use** [array_diff()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

```
$arr1 = array(1,2,3);
$arr2 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
$arr3 = array_diff($arr1, $arr2);
if (count($arr3) == 0) {
  // all of $arr1 is in $arr2
}
```