# How can I check if any value in an array is present in another array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a form that submits an array of user roles for processing by the server. Here is an example of the `$data['roles']` posted by the form:

`Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 16 )`

I want to check if `$data['roles']` contains either one of the values 16, 17, 18 or 19. As you can see in the example it contains 16. `in_array` seems like the logical choice here, but passing an *array* of values as the needle of `in_array` doesn't work:

```
$special_values = array(16, 17, 18, 19);

if (in_array($special_values, $data['roles'])) {
    // this returns false
}
```

Neither does passing the exact same values in an array:

```
$special_values = array(5, 16);

if (in_array($special_values, $data['roles'])) {
    // this also returns false
}
```

Also, switching places between the two arrays as needle and haystack doesn't change the result. If I just ask if 16 is in the array, it works fine:

```
$special_value = 16;

if (in_array($special_value, $data['roles'])) {
    // this returns true
}
```

The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) gives examples of using arrays as needles, however it seems the structure needs to be exactly the same in the haystack for it to return `true`. But then I don't get why my second example doesn't work. I'm obviously doing something wrong or missing something here.

What is the best way to check if *any* of the values in one array exists in another array?

**Edit:** [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304436) (possible duplicate) is not asking the same thing. I want to match any value in one array against any value in another. The linked question wants to match all values in one array against the values of another.

Comment: [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) is what you're looking for.

Comment: [array_intersect()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) might be a more logical choice

Comment: possible duplicate of [in\_array but needle is array, what the alternative for it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304436/in-array-but-needle-is-array-what-the-alternative-for-it)

Comment: Thanks guys. I wanted to get a true or false result and `array_intersect` gives an array of matches, but I guess I could just check `if` the result of `array_intersect` is empty and do my logic if it's not?

Comment: @BenFortune Thank for the link, however in that question he wants to check if *all* values in the needle are in the haystack. In my example I only want to know if *any* of the values in the needle is present in the haystack.

Comment: If you're voting this down please comment on why since it's a pretty legitimate question considering `in_array` takes arrays as needle. `array_intersect` gets me the result I want but I still need to do check on whether the result of array_intersect is empty or not to get a true or false result – so that involves an extra step compared to what I was trying to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you

> Using `array_intersect()`

```
$result = array_intersect($data['roles'], array(16, 17, 18, 19));
print_r($result);
```

> Using `in_array()`

```
$result = false;

foreach ($special_values as $val) {
    if (in_array($val, $data['roles'], true)) {
        $result = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, this is how I need to do it, however I only wanted `$result` to be true or false. Since `array_intersect` returns an array of matching values I'll just check if `$result` is empty or not and do my logic based on that.

Answer (score 1):

The bet way is to use array_diff and empty functions, I think:

```
if ( ! empty(array_diff($special_values, $data['roles']))) {
    throw new Exception('Some of special values are not in data roles');
}
```

or array_intersect if you want to return values which occur in both arrays.