# How to code for file upload with use defined extension using php

Tags: php, html

i have a main.php file ,in that file i have upload file code

```
<input type="file" id="uploadfile" value="Upload Key File" name="uploadfile" />
```

after clicking on submit button it will redirect to mainresult.php
in this page i write the logic to save the uploaded file in uploads/ directory and i created this directory where my php files placed.

i kept echo 's to debug it from this condition

`if(in_array($filetype, $allowed)){` from this condition echo's not printed

i tried this please help me with this .

```
<?php
echo "1111";
// Check if the form was submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
echo "222";
    // Check if file was uploaded without errors
    if(isset($_FILES["uploadfile"]) && $_FILES["uploadfile"]["error"] == 0){
echo "3333";
        $allowed = array("key");
        $filename = $_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"];
        $filetype = $_FILES["uploadfile"]["type"];
        $filesize = $_FILES["uploadfile"]["size"];

echo "4444";
        // Verify file size - 5MB maximum
        $maxsize = 50000;
        if($filesize > $maxsize) die("Error: File size is larger than the allowed limit.");

echo "555";
        // Verify MYME type of the file
        if(in_array($filetype, $allowed)){
echo "666";
            // Check whether file exists before uploading it
            if(file_exists("uploads/" . $filename)){
                echo $filename . " is already exists.";
            } else{
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadfile"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/" . $filename);
                echo "Your file was uploaded successfully.";
                $uploadstatus = "true";
            }
        } else{
            echo "Error: There was a problem uploading your file. Please try again.";
                $uploadstatus = "false";
        }
    } else{
        echo "Error: " . $_FILES["uploadfile"]["error"];
                $uploadstatus = "error";
    }
echo "000";
}
?>
```

my file extension is .key (demo.key)

Thank you

Comment: `$_FILES["uploadfile"]["type"]` will return the mime type of the file. so is not key, for know key mime type use `echo mime_content_type('demo.key')`

Comment: have you checked what `$filetype = $_FILES["uploadfile"]["type"];` contains? possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456113/check-file-extension-in-upload-form-in-php)

Comment: it prints this "application/octet-stream"

Comment: does the echos before echo"666" works ?

Comment: yes ,before 666 all echo's printed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried echoing out what the contents of $filetype is?

`$_FILES["uploadfile"]["type"]` will likely contain a mimetype like `[type] => text/plain`  or "`application/x-pem-file`".

If you echo out filetype  you can see what the mimetype is of the file you are willing to allow.

Be aware that php is not always able to tell the correct mimetype.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are using `in_array()` function wrong way i.e, the string u want to find is placed first then array.

```
$os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
if (in_array("NT",$os)) {
    echo "Got Irix";
}
```

Consider this example.

To give solution for what you are trying to do,U can do it like this

```
if(in_array("key",$filetype)){
```

Or if u want to search more than one extension , U can refer
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304436/how-can-i-use-in-array-if-the-needle-is-an-array)